# restfb Fetching Object

Tags: java, restfb

I just use restfb today and I write some demo application using restfb. But the new api version 1.30 is not match with documentation.

In Documentation, Fetching object is written like that..

```
Page page = facebookClient.fetchObject("cocacola", Page.class);
```

But new version is I can only write like that...

```
Page page = client.fetchObject("cocacola", Page.class,Parameter.with("fields", "name,id"));
```

Fetching with Parameter could be faster but I want to fetch all data from facebook page. I don't want to do with specific parameters because if i need more parameters, I have to write more. I want to fetch all data from pages. So, Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me quote the restfb documentation:

> Facebook made a breaking change with Graph API 2.4 and **you now have to provide the fields parameter to get the fields you need**. According to Facebook, reducing the default fields leads to faster performance. In the Advanced Usage section you'll find a example how the fields are requested with RestFB.

Comment: omm.. i didn't see that message from restfb document. So, Facebook is no longer support to fetch default field since API 2.4. Anyways, Thanks.